# Java SOAP SSL mutual authentication

Tags: java, soap, ssl

I have a Java application that I'm adding a JAX-WS interface to, and I've gotten it to run over HTTPS but I want to be able to do two-way SSL authentication. I have the keystores and certs setup and trusted both ways, but all the code examples I can find for verifying the client certificate on the server side doesn't work since I'm not running it in Tomcat/Glassfish, like this:

```
@Resource WebServiceContext wsCtx;

@WebMethod
public int add(@WebParam(name="i") int i, @WebParam(name="j") int j) {     

MessageContext context = wsCtx.getMessageContext();
Subject clientSubject = null;
try {
    clientSubject = SubjectAccessor.getRequesterSubject(context);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (clientSubject != null) {
    Set publicCreds = clientSubject.getPublicCredentials(
    for (Iterator it = publicCreds.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        System.out.println("Client Cert:" + it.next());
        //use our code to create the Certificate here.
        break;
     }
} else {
    System.out.println("Client Cert not set");
}
....
```

What's the native equivalent for taking a context object and checking for a client cert match? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not using a container, it's running inside a standard Java app.